# How can I pass variables from an iframe to the page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page that contains an iframe (cross domain) I have access the javascript of both: the page and the iframe page.
What I want is to pass some variables from the iframe to the page that contains that Iframe

Answer (score -1):

This is a [tutorial](https://www.roseindia.net/java/pass-value-example/pass-value-from-iframe-parent.shtml) could help you to achieve solution

for brief solution you can do this

```
var fra = document.getElementById('frameId');
// following will work on same domain (or subdomain with document.domain set) only
var fraContent = fra.contentDocument || fra.contentWindow.document;
myLinkHref = fraContent.getElementById('myLinkId').href;
```

If this is cross-domain, then you will need to have access to add script to the child frame. If not, it can't be done without a server-side proxy.